# Craftsman 917 Riding Lawnmower Not Starting

Tags: electrical, lawn-mower, backyard, engine

I have a Craftsman 917 series riding mower that I purchased last year.  It ran fine for the first month or so but after that it was intermittently having issues starting.  I noticed the connections on the ignition switch were loose and rusty so I replaced the connectors.  Now I am not able to get the starter to engage via the ignition switch but I can get it to crank (but not start) when I apply power directly to the starter.  I am not sure if the issue is in the switch/wiring or if its somewhere else in the line of startup processes.  I was able to get it started a few weeks ago and it died out after about a minute of running.  I verified that fuel was making it past the filter so I do not think that is an issue.  I used the wiring schematic from the manual as a guide when replacing the connectors.  Any thoughts on how I can determine what the issue is?  I would like to temporarily disable all the safety switches to see if there is an issue there but I am not sure how to do so.  Can I just remove the connections from the ignition switch?  ( I think it would be A1 & A2)[image]

Comment: please explain how this is a `home improvement` question

Comment: I guess it is not but I didn't really know where else to turn to for an answer to my question.

Comment: google `small engine repair forum` 
   ...... http://www.mylawnmowerforum.com/forum/5-small-engine-repair-discussion/

Comment: can you activate the starter solenoid by hand? .... otherwise, use an automobile jumper cable across the start solenoid contacts (not across the coil)    ............ i think that the ignition switch may be miswired

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  I have been trying to start it by jumper cable directly on the starter contacts and the engine turns over but does not catch.

Comment: You changed the ignition switch wiring and now it doesn't work... I'd focus my attention there.  Are you s.u.r.e the switch isn't bad?

Comment: make sure that the mowers blade switch is not energized and that the brake is fully pushed in or locked to parking brake.

Comment: @SteveSalowitz, which part of my comment do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to get it started by connecting directly to the starter but when the clutch/brake pedal was released it died so I must have either a crossed wire or bad relay somewhere

Comment: were you sitting on the seat?

Comment: Not me personally but my son was

Comment: the switch may be weight sensitive. try sitting on it yourself